# Query em coluna tipo date com filtro da semana atual

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Andei procurando um comando em mysql, que fizesse tal função. A finalidade disso é que tenho que exibir um programação de itens da semana atual. De domingo a sábado. Existe um query que faça esse filtro ? Bem a coluna é do tipo date, Y-m-d.

Comment: Você já tentou usar a função WEEK()? Se liga nesse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710342/mysql-grouping-by-week

Comment: Sim, mas ela não me retorna nenhum registro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a função `YEARWEEK` em conjunto com a `CURDATE`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tabela
 WHERE YEAR(data) = YEAR(CURDATE())
   AND YEARWEEK(data, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

---

> [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
>
> Returns the year for date, in the range 1000 to 9999, or 0 for the “zero” date.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna o ano de uma data, em um intervalo de 1000 até 9999, ou 0 para a data "zero".

---

> [`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)
>
> Returns year and week for a date.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna o ano e semana de uma data.

---

> [`CURDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)
>
> Returns the current date as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD' or YYYYMMDD format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context.

Em tradução livre:

> Retorna a data atual como o valor no formato 'YYYY-MM-DD' ou YYYYMMDD, dependendo do contexto em que a função é utilizada (string ou numérico).